# fabricjs: move object by boundingbox

Tags: fabricjs

I am new to fabricjs.

Is this possible to move object by its boundingbox?

something like :

```
object.boundingBox.left=10;
```

or method something like :

```
object.setBoundingBox("left",30);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing in Fabric but you can add your own `setBoundingBox` function:

```
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
  setBoundingBox: function(prop, val) {
    var bbox = this.getBoundingRect();
    this.set(prop, (this[prop] - bbox[prop]) + val);
    this.setCoords();
  }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
object.setBoundingBox("left",30);
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for so lone. This helpful when the object is rotated and you want to move the top/left.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property to set left with boundingRect, But you can use below code. It will set position of object according to boundingRect. You can also do the same for top position by replace left with top in  this code.

```
var  left = 10 + Math.abs(object.left - object.getBoundingRect().left )
object.left = left ;
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Hey Manoj, Thanks for the solution ! I will try this also.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that limits the movement of an object to a bounding box:

```
function limitObjMovement(rectBox, obj) {
  if ( rectBox.getLeft() <= obj.getLeft() ) {
    rectBox.setLeft( obj.getLeft() );
  }
  else if ( rectBox.getLeft() + rectBox.getWidth() >= obj.getLeft() + obj.getWidth() ) {
    rectBox.setLeft( obj.getLeft() + ( obj.getWidth() - rectBox.getWidth() ) );
  }
  if ( rectBox.getTop() <= obj.getTop() ) {
    rectBox.setTop( obj.getTop() );
  }
  else if ( rectBox.getTop() + rectBox.getHeight() >= obj.getTop() + obj.getHeight() ) {
    rectBox.setTop( obj.getTop() + ( obj.getHeight() - rectBox.getHeight() ) );
  }
}

canvas.on("object:moving", function() {
  limitObjMovement(boundingBoxObj, movingObj);
});
```